# Firesstore export: Not found: project 'project_id' does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I was trying to export some files from gcloud Firestore.

When I put
`gcloud config set  project project_id` 
It says `Updated property [core/project]`. However, when I input `gcloud firestore export gs://<PATH>` , the error message is `NOT_FOUND: Project project_id does not exist`. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The projectID can be find in the home page of your project

[image]

Replace the `project_id` by this value and it should work better!

Comment: I did use the project id listed here, but still it says the the project does not exist

Comment: Do you use the project ID and not the project Name? And the error is the same NOT FOUND?

Comment: Yes, I do use the project_id at gcloud config set project project-id  step. That part works fine.  the NOT_FOUND happens when glcoud export

Comment: Can you try this: `gcloud firestore export gs:// --project=<project_id>` (by changing the <project_id> by the real value)?

Comment: Is Firestore active on the project? Can you browse it on the console?

Comment: How to check if Firestore is active on the project?

Comment: Use this command `gcloud services list |grep firestore`. If a line is answered, that means firestore is already enabled. For a particular project (your case) prefer this one `gcloud services list --project=<project_id> | grep firestore` (by changing the <project_id> by the real value)

Comment: I ran that command. Nothing returned and there is no report of error. My guess is that Firestore may not be active. How to set it active?

Comment: `gcloud services enable firestore.googleapis.com --project=<project_id>` And then try again your export.

Comment: I still got the NOT_FOUND error, though gcloud services list |grep firestore will return a line now

Comment: Can you perform a `gcloud projects list` and see if you find your project in the list?

Comment: Yes, I can find my project in the list

Comment: Did you try this on Cloud Shell? Is the result different?

Comment: I only tested on cloud shell on console.cloud.google.com and got the results above. Didn't try anywhere else